# Servlet data not loading into a variable in extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

In my code i am calling servlet from javascript using ajax request. Servlet data is showing in messegebox of success function. But it is not loading into a variable myData in javascript. data from servlet is in json format. please help me. here is my code.

```
var myData=null;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'MyDataServlet',
    method:'GET',
    loadMask: true,
    scope: this,
    success: 
    function ( result, request ) { 
      Ext.MessageBox.alert('success', result.responseText); 
       myData =Ext.decode(result.responseText);
       console.log(myData);
       store.loadData(myData);

    },
    failure: 
        function ( result, request) { 
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: What does responseText contain? It's a valid JSON string ?

Comment: Yes.ResponseText contain valid JSON string.

Comment: Judging by the code you have to get an object or exception. Show ResponseText.

Answer (score 0):

The first "A" in "AJAX" stands for "asynchronous", which means that the application flow continues before the server sends back the response (I think "fire and forget" is a useful analogy).
In your case, `myData` is only assigned after the response arrives and you **cannot** assume rest of the code executes before that happens. Whatever you want to do with `myData`, you'll need to call it from the `success` callback.

Comment: Read the question more carefully: *"data is showing in messegebox of success function. But it is not loading into a variable myData in javascript"* . That was the very thing I thought of when I saw `myData` declared outside the `success` callback, anyway. The only reason OP would want to do that would be to reuse the value in another place, and that's not the correct way to do this.

Comment: There is no problem declaring myData variable outside. Success function is just a closure and it's able to use myData. Message box doesn't shows myData, it shows responseText received from server.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused; the OP explicitly says *"data **is** showing in messegebox"*, because *everything* inside the callback is executed after the value is returned from server. On the other hand, any code using `myData` *outside* the callback will not see the correct value. Please refrain from voting on answers until you understand them fully.

Comment: Can't you see the code after ajax request? I can't. So i can't understand your reason of writing of all this.